# Make GRUB boot to Usb pendrives

Tags: usb, boot, virtualbox, virtualization, grub

I would like to boot usb pendrives using grub.

An example is using a VirtualBox VM with a minimal install of Debian (Just the console).

Debian will install GRUB by default, i would like to use the grub console to boot an USB Thumb drive attached to the machine.

How could this be possible?

GRUB doesn't list the partitions on usb thumb drive. I used

```
insmod uhci
insmod usbms
```

But GRUB doesn't detect any partitions from usb.

Is there a way to force the usb detection?

PD: SuperGrubDisk didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have had much better results with [grub4dos](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/) than with Linux grub. If you have a windows box or a vm, then all you need is just unpack the files from the archive, and then run `grubinst_gui.exe` - this will write the USB drive boot sector and make it bootable. There is a [grub4dos walkthrough](http://www.themudcrab.com/acronis_grub4dos.php) available with an example `menu.lst`.

I use this setup for a multiboot USB flash stick, that can book directly from some ISO images (memory-mapped or disk file-based), any bootable floppy image, and things like [supergrubdisk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/), [partedmagic](http://partedmagic.com), BartPE, etc.